# Resizing and Repeating an Image

Tags: image, matlab, resize

I've run into a problem with images. I am trying to take an image and make it 1/4th of it's original size, then have it repeated as a 2x2 matrix. Kind-of like this:

```
Given an input image:
           ---------------------
           |                   |
           |                   |
           |       IMG         | 
           |                   |
           |                   |
           ---------------------

   Firstly, shrink it to 1/4 of its original size:
           -----------
           |   img   | 
           |         | 
           |---------|

   Then concatenate it into a "2x2 array" of the shrunken image:
           ---------------------
           |   img   |   img   |
           |         |         |
           |---------|---------| 
           |   img   |   img   |
           |         |         |
           ---------------------
```

What I am struggling with is the fact that I do not know how to make it into a 2x2 array. Any suggestions? This isn't actually HW this time :) It's for studying purposes. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function[newImg] = immultiply(picture)

Image = imread(picture); %// Reads in the picture
[r, c, l] = size(Image); %// Finds the images rows, columns and layers
rows = round(r ./ 2); %// Divides up the rows
columns = round(c ./ 2); %// Divides up the columns

newImg = cat(3,rows,columns,3); %// Creates my image, but just gives me a blank thing
imshow(newImg)


end
```

I will update as I work on it further. Thanks!

Comment: For the concatenating part, you can use `repmat`: `repmat(img,2,2)`, but that won't be `2 x 2` per se, it would be more like double-sized `img` along rows and columns.

Comment: you can't use imresize right?

Comment: If you were trying to have a cell array, then of course you can have a `2 x 2` sized cell array as output with `repmat({img},2,2)`.

Comment: I've never learned those functions. We can do resize, but the drawn out way that didn't seem right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer perfectly covers what you've asked,

however, if you don't want to use `imresize` and `repmat`,

```
im = imread('peppers.png');
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(im) 
im1 = im(1 : 2 : end, 1 : 2 : end,:); 
im2 = [im1 im1; im1 im1]; 
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(im2);
```

[image]

Comment: The line `im(1 : 2 : end, 1 : 2 : end,:)` simply applies __downsampling__. It would be better to apply some [__anti-aliasing filter__](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)) first. For example, average every block of 2x2 pixels

Comment: This method is _good_ if you don't want to use `repmat` and `imresize`. However since you are not interpolating you _lose_ half of the information.

Comment: @LuisMendo, aliasing happens when you apply a filter, here we are just removing some samples. I don't think there will be a problem.

Comment: @Kamtal. No. Aliasing happens when you remove samples. The filter prior to downsampling prevents that aliasing from happening.

Comment: @LuisMendo, Since filters deal with frequency components of signal aliasing is possible applying a filter to do this work, but since we are working in time domain I seriously doubt we have any problems.

Comment: @Kamtal Sorry, but I have to say you are totally wrong on that. [This picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/AliasingSines.svg/300px-AliasingSines.svg.png) should be explanatory: removing samples changes the apparent frequenbcy of the sinusoid (i.e. aliasing)

Comment: @LuisMendo, then wouldn't we have an aliasing effect on new image?

Comment: @Kamtal The aliasing can be visible or not depending on the image. To give you an example: suppose the image consists of zeros and ones (black and white pixels) alternatively, forming a very fine checker board. Looked at from a distance you get a smooth grey image. Now downsample as in your code, and you get a completely black or a completely white image. There you go: aliasing. An anti-aliasing filter would take the average of neighbouring pixels. For this image it would transform all pixels into 0.5 (instead of alternating zeros and ones), so that  removing samples you'd still get 0.5 values

Comment: @LuisMendo, thanks for your time and information, It's still confusing for me. I should do some studying.

Comment: Kamtal, I think my answer might address part of @LuisMendo's comments.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Correct on all accounts.  When someone tries to naively downsample an image to try and resize it, I give them the checkerboard example.  Subsampling by 2 would give a completely dark or white image, depending on how the pixels are alternating.  Smoothing the image is what is needed.  This is actually the technique used in 1D signal processing, and 2D is simply an extension to another dimension.  However, with respect to the OP's current knowledge in MATLAB, then this is probably the most suitable technique... though signal processing guys like you or me are cringing.

Comment: @rayryeng, I've understood my mistake thanks to LuisMendo. The example was pretty clear thank for that.

Comment: @Kamtal - No worries!  Just wanted to put in my two cents :)

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for your comments :-) I find it funny that you also use the checkerboard example; I made it up just for the occasion. But I guess it's the first example that comes to mind

Answer (score 4):

The previous two answers are correct, and I originally worked on this just playing around and wasn't going to post it, but with a slight modification I think it addresses part of Luis Mendo's comments on Kamtal's answer.

My original thought was, why throw away data? If you're downsampling to 1/4 size but plotting 4 of them, you have room for **all** of the data:

```
img1 = imread('myimage.png');
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(img1) 
img2 = img1([1:2:end, 2:2:end], [1:2:end, 2:2:end]); 
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(img2);
```

The resulting top-left quadrant of `img2` will be exactly what Kamtal's answer produces: a nearest-neighbor interpolation of the pixels with odd-valued x and y coordinates. The other 3 will be (even/odd), (odd/even), (even/even). Every pixel in `img1` appears in `img2` and each sub-image can be slightly different.

If instead we want to combine the data from each of the 4 images into a single image without throwing away *all* of the data, we can change this up slightly. We just take the average of the 4 images. Note that `img2` is the same here as above, I'm just breaking out the calculations to make it obvious.

```
img1 = imread('myimage.png');
subplot(1,3,1),imshow(img1) 
img2a = img1(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
img2b = img1(1:2:end, 2:2:end);
img2c = img1(2:2:end, 1:2:end);
img2d = img1(2:2:end, 2:2:end);
img2 = [img2a img2b; img2c img2d];
subplot(1,3,2),imshow(img2);
img3a = (img2a + img2b + img2c + img2d)/4;
img3 = [img3a img3a; img3a img3a];
subplot(1,3,3),imshow(img3);
```

Here `img3` shows 4 identical images, all the result of downsampling the original image using mean filtering.

To do this with a filter, you would use the kernel:

```
[0.25 0.25]
[0.25 0.25]
```

This just takes the average of the 4 elements in the neighborhood. With the origin of the kernel at (1,1) your interpolated, downsampled image would be in the odd-numbered rows/columns as before:

```
img1 = imread('myimage.png');
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(img1) 
h = [0.25, 0.25; 0.25, 0.25]   //% define the mean filter kernel
img2a = imfilter(img1, h);     //% filter before applying Kamtal's solution
img2b = img2a(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
img2 = [img2b img2b; img2b img2b]; 
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(img2);
```

The resulting image should be the same as `img3` above.

(Incidentally, mean filtering with a 2x2 kernel and then downsampling to 1/4 size is essentially bilinear interpolation. `imresize` uses bicubic interpolation by default, so its results will be slightly different.)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the instructions `imresize` and `repmat`

```
i = imread('lena.png');

figure(1),subplot(1,2,1),imshow(i) 
[n,m,d] = size(i);

newI = imresize(i,0.5); 
finalI = repmat(newI,2,2); 
figure(1),subplot(1,2,2),imshow(finalI);
```

newI is the image resized to 1/2. This is equivalent to shrink the image to 1/4.
finalI is the final image repeated 4 times. `repmat` is concatenating the matrix 2x2 times.

I strongly recommend you to check the documentation of these two functions:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html

Comment: I wouldn't exactly feel comfortable using those on a test though. This 'homework' is to help with the test next week. We were not taught imresize or repmat.

Comment: Well.. if you are gonna work with Matlab don't try to reinvent the wheel. So many things are already implemented and Matlab is powerful if you learn how to use those.

Comment: If you want to properly resize an image, then use `imresize`.  It properly applies anti-aliasing and handles edge cases, so this post is right on the money.  However, because this is as an exercise to test an understanding of MATLAB with techniques learned so far without using other functions, this needs to be properly stated in the problem statement so we don't suggest things that can't be used.